# character scanning via user switch-case

Tags: c, arrays, function, for-loop, switch-statement

I'm trying to write a code that takes numbers via user and reads character 'e' or ' ' (space) also numbers. I mean a number 'e' or space 'e' a number 'e' or space and so forth.But I get absurd numbers. The program will show the added number. If '\n' entered the taking numbers will stop(scanf will stop). (I'm sorry for title because I don't have any idea about title)
Where is my wrong. Thank you for all appreciated answers.

Example input:

- **e** 1 8 7 2 3 6
- or
- **e** 1 **e** 8 **e** 7 **e** 2 **e** 3 **e** 6

---

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    #define MAX 10

    void addq ( int *, int, int *, int * ) ;
    void test();

    int main( )
    {

        test();
        return 0;
    }


    void test(){

        int arr[MAX] ;
        int i, front, rear,num ;
        char ch;

        front = rear = -1 ;
        scanf("%c",&ch);
        /* initialise data member */
        switch(ch){

        case 'e':
        case ' ':
            for ( i = 0 ; i < MAX; i++ ){
            arr[i] = scanf("%d",&num);
            scanf("%c",&ch);
            addq ( arr, num, &front, &rear );
            }
            break;

        }

        printf ( "\nElements in the circular queue: " ) ;
        display ( arr ) ;

}
void display ( int * arr )
{
int i ;
printf ( "\n" ) ;
for ( i = 0 ; i < MAX ; i++ )
    printf ( "%d\t", arr[i] ) ;
printf ( "\n" ) ;
}
    /* adds an element to the queue */
    void addq ( int *arr, int item, int *pfront, int *prear )
    {
        if ( ( *prear == MAX - 1 && *pfront == 0 ) || (  *prear + 1 == *pfront ) )
        {
            printf ( "\nQueue is full." ) ;
            return ;
        }

        if ( *prear == MAX - 1 )
            *prear = 0 ;
        else
            ( *prear )++ ;

        arr[*prear] = item ;

        if ( *pfront == -1 )
            *pfront = 0 ;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use

```
scanf("%c",&ch);
```

it skips whitespaces. You should use

```
int ch; // Use type int, not char.
ch = fgetc(stdin);
```

Comment: I don't want to skip whitespaces. Because when the user presses enter the scannig must be stopped. I mean '\n'

Comment: Then test the output of `fgetc();`:   if(ch == '\n'){stop scanning}.

Comment: i entered `e 1 e 8 e 7 e 2 e 3 e 6 e 4 e 3 e 2` but the program shows `1 1 8 8 7 7 2 2 3 3`

Comment: @Soner, it sounds like you have other logic errors in your code. It's not clear from your post how many numbers do you expect to see after an `'e'` or a `' '`. Your use of `for ( i = 0 ; i < MAX; i++ ){` to read numbers does not match with the sample input.

Comment: @RSahu When I press enter the scannig must be stopped. Besides, The input can be written with spaces or 'e' by 'e'. But when start to enter inputs there must begin with 'e' like `e 1 8 7 2 3 6` or `e 1 e 8 e 7 e 2 e 3 e 6` after pressing enter display(arr) will show the numbers on screen like `1 8 7 2 3 6`

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX 10

typedef struct q {
    int arr[MAX];
    int front, rear;
} Q;

void init_q(Q *q);
void add_q (Q *q, int v);
void display_q(Q *q);
void test();

int main( ){
    test();
    return 0;
}

void test(){
    int num, end = 0;
    char ch;
    Q q;
    init_q(&q);

    scanf("%c", &ch);
    while(!end){
        switch(ch){
        case 'e':
        case ' ':
            if(1==scanf("%d", &num))
                add_q(&q, num);
            scanf("%c", &ch);
            break;
        case '\n':
            end = 1;
            break;
        default:
            printf("invalid input(%c)\n", ch);
            scanf("%c", &ch);
        }
    }

    printf("\nElements in the circular queue: ") ;
    display_q(&q) ;
}

void init_q(Q *q){
    q->front = q->rear = -1;
}
int empty_q(Q *q){
    return q->front == -1;
}
int full_q(Q *q){
    return (q->rear == MAX - 1 && q->front == 0) || q->rear + 1 == q->front;
}
void add_q (Q *q, int item){
    if(full_q(q)){
        printf( "\nQueue is full.\n");
        return ;
    }

    if( q->rear == MAX - 1 )
        q->rear = 0;
    else
        q->rear++;

    q->arr[q->rear] = item;

    if(q->front == -1 )
        q->front = 0;
}
void display_q(Q *q){
    if(!empty_q(q)){
        int i = q->front;
        printf("\n");
        for(;;){
            printf("%d\t", q->arr[i]);
            if(i++ == q->rear)
                break;
            if(i == MAX)
                i = 0;
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```